# Javascript Data Filter based on Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm very new to Javascript and I'm trying to filter/update data based on a checkbox. If you see below I can filter the data based on values in the data I created (dataset2). Dataset3 is the problem...  I want to click on the checkboxes and update the dataset based on the values that are checked.

First, I'm not sure how to pass the array of values into the filter (e.g. how would I pass "Books" && "Supplies" into the filter.  As you can see in dataset2 I can only get it to equal "Books".  Second, how do I get it to update when checkboxes are checked/unchecked.  I created a fiddle for this also.  Thanks you. https://jsfiddle.net/at2046/mqjyjfox/8/

```
var dataset = [['Books','GEB'],
                                ['Books','Decision Theory'],
                                ['Supplies','Pencil'],
                ['Supplies','Paper']
                ];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dataset;

var dataset2 = dataset.filter(function (el) {
        return el[0] == "Books";
        });

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = dataset2;


$(":checkbox").change(function() {
var dataset3 = dataset.filter(function(el) {
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('result');
for (var index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
return el[0] == checkboxes[index].value;
    }
});

document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = dataset3;
});
```

Comment: You are not capturing any events, so there is no code executing when the checkboxes are clicked. Also `vals.split(',')` has no effect as a statement on its own, you need to assign it. Why not keep it an array from the start and use `push`. And `return el[0] = test` is an assignment, not a comparison. Too many issues...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistakes.  I'll keep learning.

Comment: I think I've fixed some of the stupid errors.  I tried to capture the checkbox event .change and then fire the function for filtering the data but I'm not sure if that's working. The checkboxes[index].value does filter the data correctly when I place a 0 or 1 manually in for index...  I'm not following how it cycles through that index and then pushes the results ...  Any more pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you added a $(:checkbox'), which is a jQuery syntax and you didn't have the library loaded in your fiddle.

Then, you use a `return` inside the `for`, which means that at the first iteration (choice Books) the script will exit returning only the elements belonging to the first item in the choice list.

An option is to replace the `for` for a `while` to check if the el[0] exists in any of the choices.

Lastly, you weren't checking if the checkboxes are checked, which means it would return everything no matter the state of the check box.

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var dataset3 = dataset.filter(function(el) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('result');
        var index = 0;
        var found = false;
        while (index < checkboxes.length && !found) {
            if (checkboxes[index].checked && el[0] == checkboxes[index].value) found=true;
            ++index;
        }
        return found;
    });

    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = dataset3;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mqjyjfox/10/

Comment: Thank you!.  Now to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used cuisines for my checkbox items. The following code snippet gives the logic for checkboxes filtering. `handleCuisineChange` is the function that contains the logic. The length of `for` loop is 8 since the number of cuisines (the number of checkbox items) I have taken here is 8. Replace the `cuisines` here with your checkbox data. Apply this logic and your checkbox items are ready for filtering.

Inside `axios` I used my own backend API `getCuisine` and port number `7000`.

```html
axios I used my own backend API getCuisine and port number 7000.

handleCuisineChange=(cuisine_id)=>
    {
        const {cuisineArray}=this.state; //an empty array declared in constructor
       
        if (cuisineArray.indexOf(cuisine_id) == -1)
        {
            cuisineArray.push(cuisine_id);
        }
        else
        {
            var index=cuisineArray.indexOf(cuisine_id);
            cuisineArray.splice(index,1);
        }    

        const {cuisineArray2}=this.state; //an empty array declared in constructor
        let i=0;
        for (i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            if(cuisineArray[i]==undefined)
            {
                cuisineArray2[i]=cuisineArray[0];
            }
            else
            {
                cuisineArray2[i]=cuisineArray[i];
            }
        }

        this.props.history.push(`/checking3?cuisine_id1=${cuisineArray2[0]}&cuisine_id2=${cuisineArray2[1]}&cuisine_id3=${cuisineArray2[2]}&cuisine_id4=${cuisineArray2[3]}&cuisine_id5=${cuisineArray2[4]}&cuisine_id6=${cuisineArray2[5]}&cuisine_id7=${cuisineArray2[6]}&cuisine_id8=${cuisineArray2[7]}`);
        let filterObj={cuisine_id1:cuisineArray2[0],cuisine_id2:cuisineArray2[1],cuisine_id3:cuisineArray2[2],cuisine_id4:cuisineArray2[3],cuisine_id5:cuisineArray2[4],cuisine_id6:cuisineArray2[5],cuisine_id7:cuisineArray2[6],cuisine_id8:cuisineArray2[7]};
        axios(
            {
                method:'POST',
                url:`http://localhost:7000/getCuisine`,
                headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                data:filterObj
            }
        )
        .then(res=>
            {
                this.setState({restaurants:res.data.restaurants});
            })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }

render()
    {
        const {restaurants}=this.state;
        return(
            
                <div>
                   
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"1"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > North Indian </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines"  id={"2"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("2")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > south indian </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"3"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("3")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > chinese </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"4"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > fast food </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"5"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > Street food </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"6"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > American </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"7"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > Italian </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"8"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > Mexican </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                </div>
       )
  } //render end
```